# How much pressure can typical TEC modules withstand?

Tags: peltier, diy, cooling

Since I have not found an answer online. Nor any data sheets specifying, I can conduct my own test. But why not then post it online for others to see, I'm sure others will be searching it in a question form.

So I am worried that TEC127 modules can be crushed if too much weight is placed on top, but we also want to keep them in tight contact with the heatsink. What is the safe range?

If no one has tested, I will monitor the performance of a single module while adding weight to the heatsink on top of it. It will get crushed eventually. One source stated that it shouldn't be more than 1 kg, which seems pretty low to me, and implies that we cannot place a radiator on top without additional legs supporting the heatsink.

Overall I have nearly a 100 modules with varying ratings and I am building a setup with many layers, and the higher (hotter) stages have more of them side by side. Supplying them all with 2 volts each, some of them even 1 volt, the temperature difference on each layer will be small but the COP will be really high. With many cascading layers I can get 30°C below ambient, even if each layer only has under 5°C difference. The COP must be comparable to a common kitchen fridge.

Anyway the main question is about the weight bearing. How much pressure is too risky to get them crushed?

Comment: Sorry it got posted into electrical. I just came from another question involving TECs and registered to ask. But also, what other categories does this fit?

Answer (score 0):

The answer? A bit, the TECs have bismuth telluide crystals that are sandwiched between two cermaic plates. The manufacturer should have info on how much normal force they can support.

I'll summarize a few points of TEC mounting:

1. An even force is needed across the TEC, if there is a torque on one side of the module, with more force, it will crack.
2. There should be a very smooth machine finish on the metal if you are mounting it to metal, any roughness can create uneven heat distribution and cause problems.
3. You can put a few inch-lbs on the module of pressure, consult the mfg.
4. The fixture cannot move or it will put strain on the modules and they will crack in time. Don't ever put mechanical shock on the module (like if your shipping the fixture needs to protect from dropping)
5. Don't thermally stress the module, by putting large temperature gradients on it.

There is a good guide here: https://customthermoelectric.com/tech-info/install/tec-installation.html